# How to set default schema name for Spring Data JPA queries?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to set default schema for postgresql. When I try to set property("hibernate.default_schema") and also update table anotation with schema prop, hibernate still generates query without any schema name like below;

```
select log0_.id as id1_0_ from log log0_
```

When I change table name to "dbo.log", I can get resultSet without any error.

```
 @Table(name = "dbo.log")
```

Is there any way to set default schema for postgresql queries?

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.test.repository.postgresql",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgresqlEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "postgresqlTransactionManager"
)
public class PostgreSQLConfig {

    ....

    @Bean(name = "postgresqlEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("postgresqlDatasource") DataSource postgresqlDatasource) {

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", hibernateDDLAuto);
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.naming.physical-strategy", hibernatePhysicalStrategy);
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "dbo");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.test.entity.postgresql");
        factory.setDataSource(postgresqlDatasource);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

}
```

Here is my entity class;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "log", schema = "dbo")
public class Log{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you defining your own `EntityManagerFactory` if you use Spring Boot?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I got 3 different database server(PostgreSQL, SQLServer1, SQLServer2). Every db has own config, entities and repositories.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using application.properties

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://myserver:5432/mydb
>
> **spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=myschema**
>
> spring.datasource.username=myuser
>
> spring.datasource.password=mypassword
>
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

Answer (score 1):

That should be declard in the JDBC Connection URL in the `DataSource`. The URL schema looks like: `jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database`, where database is the schema.

If that's not enough set also in the URL the `currentSchema`.

> Specify the schema (or several schema separated by commas) to be set
>   in the search-path. This schema will be used to resolve unqualified
>   object names used in statements over this connection.

Here are the docs for the JDBC Driver: 
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

Comment: currentSchema is not working when I update connection url prop like "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?currentSchema=dbo"

Comment: Are you sure that you are not mixing Postgres with SQL Server here? dbo sounds like SQL Server. Try setting currentSchema=mydb.

Comment: No I am not mixing. I also create a schema named "dbo" for postgreSQL. I can fetch results with  @Table(name = "dbo.log") and with connection url "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"

Comment: Could be also a thing with the namingStrategy. I've never used this. I would remove this and try it just with the URL. You could also add in the answer how you configure the `DataSource`.